# 3d surface image for given datasets

Tags: matlab, python

[image]

I have some data that looks like as follows

x-cor  y-cor  z-cor

0.02  0.0251  0.02

0.01  0.0257  0.02

0.014  0.02   0.03

0.023  0.003  0.05

0.013  0.002  0.77

....................

....................

I would like to draw an image like the above. Can you please suggest a way to start that in Matlab/python?

image source: https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/109/37/14761.full.pdf

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What you are talking about is a surface plot of irregularly spaced data. A starting point is this tutorial, https://fabrizioguerrieri.com/blog/surface-graphs-with-irregular-dataset/

Comment: Thank you so much Maxim! I am following the link you have shared!